# ASP.NET 3.0 mvc app crash after file/image upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, visual-studio-2019

I am using ASP.Net Core 3.0 and I want to create a new product with images but my app crashes after i choose the image from the file upload and push the 'create' button. I tried to debug on my controller but the app crashes before it reaches the controller. Everything else is working on create action. When I comment out the file input, everything else works fine. 
I just want the image to be posted with the rest of my ProductModelVM so I can handle then in my controller.

Here is my ProductPostVM model:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebshopAppMVC.Models
{
    public class ProductPostVM
    {
        //[JsonPropertyName("id")]
        //public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("price")]
        public double Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("manufacturerId")]
        // A product has one manufacturer
        public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [JsonPropertyName("categories")]
        // products can have many Categories
        public ICollection<int> Categories { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("images")]
        // one product can have many images
        public IEnumerable<IFormFile> Images { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my Create.cshtml:

```
@model WebshopAppMVC.Models.ProductPostVM
@using System.Text.Json;
@using WebshopAppMVC.Models;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    List<ManufacturerVM> manufacturers = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ManufacturerVM>>(@Context.Session.GetString("manufacturers"));
    SelectList manufacturersData = new SelectList(manufacturers, "Id", "Name");
    List<CategoryVM> categories = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<CategoryVM>>(@Context.Session.GetString("categories"));
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>ProductPostVM</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            @*<div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>*@
            @*</div>*@
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ManufacturerId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ManufacturerId" class="form-control" asp-items=@manufacturersData>
                    <option value="">Please select</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ManufacturerId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Categories" class="control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            @{
                                int cnt = 0;

                                foreach (var category in categories)
                                {
                                    if (cnt++ % 3 == 0)
                                    {
                                    @:</tr><tr>
                                    }
                                    @:<td>
                                        <input type="checkbox"
                                               name="Categories"
                                               value="@category.Id"
                                               @(Html.Raw(category.Assigned ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
                                        @category.Name
                                    @:</td>
                                }
                            @:</tr>
                            }
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <dl>
                    <dt>
                        <label asp-for="Images"></label>
                    </dt>
                    <dd>
                        <input asp-for="Images" type="file" multiple>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
    </div>
```

and this is the code in my controller for the create action:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ProductPostVM productPost)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //foreach (string file in Request.)
                //{
                //    var postedFile = Request.Files[file];
                //    postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/") + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName));
                //}
                var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

                var productContent = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(productPost), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("https://localhost:44352/api/products"), productContent).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
            }

            return View(productPost);
        }
```

**Here is a picture of how my view looks:**

[image: create.cshtml]

Comment: Which browser are you using when you run your program?

Comment: i'm using brave, because of your question i tried it in chrome and it worked! So i think i'm never using brave again ;) thanks for your help!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This behavior in specific has been attributed to a browser problem and not `Visual Studio` in general. As per this [article](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/261622/dotnetexe-crashes-when-upload-files-use-debug-mode.html) and this [article](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/556910/uploading-file-in-mvc-project-under-debug-forces-p.html), this behavior was generally observed when using browsers like `Brave` in this case and `Yandex`. Sometimes even `Chrome` shows this behavior but it is not consistent (at least that is what I have observed).

A possible solution would be changing your browser type to use ideal browsers like Chrome, Firefox or Edge.

For users using `Brave` browser, an alternative would be:

> Turning the Shields off(down) stops the crashing. You can do this by
> clicking the shield icon to the right of the URL.

Comment: Having this issue with Brave. Would like to have a way to capture the exception somewhere but no luck. Switching to Firefox for testing did work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `<form>` tag is using the wrong method attribute. `method="get"` is the [default value](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp).

Try

```
<form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Comment: that still doens't work for me, its no difference, when i go to visual studio bebug output it says: The program '[18948] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[18948] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: You might have to clear cache or use developer tools to ensure that the new changes are reflected.