# blazor server file upload silently crashes server

Tags: c#, file-upload, blazor

I'm testing image upload on my blazor server application. For this, my `.razor` component looks like this:

```
@page "/uploadtest"

<h1>Upload Example</h1>
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <p>A simple example with a model, which can upload images</p>
        <label>
            Load Images:
            <InputFile OnChange="@UploadImages" multiple accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" />
        </label>

    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <p>To use this application, please <a href="Identity/Account/Login">log in</a> or <a href="Identity/Account/Register">register</a> a new account! </p>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I put the code-behind in a separate `.razor.cs` file, the class looks like this:

```
public partial class UploadExample: ComponentBase
{ 
    #region Protected Properties
    [Inject]
    protected AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider { get; private set; }

    [Inject]
    protected IWebHostEnvironment WebHostEnvironment { get; private set; }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// File upload
    /// Only images of type .jpg and png are allowed here.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected async Task UploadImages(InputFileChangeEventArgs ifc)
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            try
            {
                string userId = user.FindFirst(c => c.Type.Contains("nameidentifier"))?.Value;
                string currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss");
                string path = Path.Combine(WebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, $@"UserData/{userId}/UploadTest/{currentTime}");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                var files = ifc.GetMultipleFiles();
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(path, file.Name);
                    await using FileStream fs = new(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                    await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(fs);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Here are my issues:

- For some reason after the `UploadImages()` function is executed, the application silently crashes. I can't find anything useful in the console output nor are any exceptions thrown, it just stops with code -1. The files however are successfully uploaded to the expected folder. Furthermore, the crash seems to be independent from the function.
- The code currently stores the files in the `wwwroot` folder, which I am sure is a bad idea. I already have a data access layer, which is a separate class library and handles all the database stuff. Basically, I want only the path to the images stored in the database, but the data access library should still handle storage of the a images. Is it common to give `IBrowserFile` objects to a separate class library? If not, how would the data be sent to the data access layer?

**Edit**
In the Dev-Options of my browser, I get the following error:

> Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 ().'.

as soon as I select any file for upload. I tested different things (with/without authorization, calling/not calling the `UploadImages()` functions, etc...)

Comment: What does the stack trace say? And instead of passing `IBrowserFile` around, I'd use a `Stream`

Comment: @mu88 give me a sec, I'll check. Another thing I just realized is, that the "silent crash" only happens on my default browser which is Brave, a Chromium based browser. On MS Edge, the issue doesn't seem to be apparent.

Comment: Problem is I can't really watch the call stack, since the program just..."exits". No exception is thrown. Also if I set a breakpoint in the method above, it is hit, but then immediately the whole program shuts down.

Comment: What is the last line of code you can reach without crashing the program? And is your code on GitHub?

Comment: Unfortuanely this is company code, so I can't share the whole project. Anyways, the problem is, that even I use `<InputFile/>` tag completely empty (meaning no attributes, no code called), the crash happens.

Comment: Which version of .NET? 6.0.102? I'll give it a short try

Comment: .NET 5.0. Thanks! In the meantime I have disabled 'just my code' in the debugger. `Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
A task was canceled.` is the only exception I can see now.

Comment: So I have just created a completely new blank blazor server application and only added `<InputFile/>` to the `Counter.razor` page. Same issue, program just closes as soon as the file selection window closes in Brave browser.

Comment: @mu88 before you search a long time, it could be this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28547

Comment: Ah you were faster :D

Comment: My issue was caused by `RequestImageFileAsync` to resize the uploaded image. No errors, just hanging and eventually timing out and disconnecting. Now, I'm resizing the image with a different method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I stumbled across that issue: [Blazor Server inputfile Crashes with certain Chromium Based Browsers](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28547)
That sounds pretty much like what you're experiencing, right?

To further proof that theory, please download the following code: https://github.com/mu88/StackOverflow_BlazorServerFileUpload
That's basically a simplified copy of your code which works on my machine in Chrome and Firefox. If you can run that code on your machine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Brave, I think we can be sure that we found the culprit.

Comment: That's 3 hours of my live I won't get back^^ Anyway, I marked your answer as correct, since it will lead future users to the core of the issue directly :)

Comment: That's right  but anyways, we've learned something - and be it only a bug ^^

Comment: Mine is happening in production and when debugging. Just started after updating from Net5 to Net 6.

Comment: More on this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59611796

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error in Google Chrome running a **server-side** Blazor project. Inside my appsettings.Development.json, I set all of my logging levels to debug before finally finding this error inside Visual Studio > Output:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionHandler: Debug: Error when processing requests.

System.IO.InvalidDataException: The maximum message size of 32768B was exceeded. The message size can be configured in AddHubOptions.
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionHandler`1.DispatchMessagesAsync(HubConnectionContext connection)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionHandler`1.RunHubAsync(HubConnectionContext connection)
```

The solution is to go into your Program.cs and add the following hub option:

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddHubOptions(options =>
{
    // maximum message size of 2MB
    options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 2000000;
});
```

Here's a sample of my image upload code, which I didn't need to change:

```
// maximum message size of 2MB
using (Stream stream = args.File.OpenReadStream(2000000))
{
    await using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

        imageBuffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBuffer);
    ...
}
```